# How do I update a defaultdict using a loop?

Tags: python, key, defaultdict

I created a dictionary

```
TTR_of_speakers = defaultdict(int)
TTR_of_speakers = {}
```

and I wrote a program that does some computations that results in a value called TTR.

```
for record in cwrecords:
    if record["speaker_name"] == "Joe Biden":
        text = record["text"]
        processed = nlp(text)
        textw = [t.lemma_ for t in processed]
        N += len(textw)
        total_types |= set(textw)
        V = len(total_types)
        TTR = float(V)/float(N)
```

How do I put the TTR value into the dictionary with the key as Joe Biden?

Comment: you mean `TTR_of_speakers[record["speaker_name"]] = TTR`?

Comment: thanks you're the best